# Ms access database Like query is not working

Tags: php, sql, database, ms-access

I have been using access database recently (for the easiness of using it by converting the excel data

in to the access db). When i died the sql query and executed in the query window in access it works

perfectly , but not the $query->fetch() . here is what i have tried

```
<?php
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "website-mub/db/rates.accdb";

if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
        if ($db)
            echo "success";
        $sql = "SELECT Prefix,[Named Route Name],[New Rate] FROM ratesheet";
        if (!empty($countryCode) && !empty($countryName))
            $sql .= " WHERE Prefix LIKE CStr(" . $countryCode . ") AND [Named Route Name] LIKE '" . $countryName . " *'";
        else if (!empty($countryCode))
            $sql .= " WHERE Prefix LIKE CStr(" . $countryCode . ")";
        else if (!empty($countryName))
            $sql .= " WHERE [Named Route Name] LIKE '" . $countryName . " *'";

//      die($sql);  // The query exceutes properly

$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch();


if (!empty($row)) {
    print_r($row);  // not giving any results
    exit();
}
?>
```

**UPDATE :-**

For querying the `integer` fields `'country code'` using Cstr in the db it giving some results (But its too repeating 
unwanted data ) . And for the `text`  type like `'country name'` it not working at all .

Thanks .

**Table Structure**

[image]

**Sample Query**

```
SELECT Prefix,[Named Route Name],[New Rate] FROM ratesheet WHERE [Named Route Name] LIKE 'Afghanistan*'
```

Comment: please post some data both source and expected result. why you use `LIKE` instead of `=` for exact matching? when you check with `*` the `LIKE` keyword is useful but it is not when doing exact comparison as you do with `$countryCode`.

Comment: okay i will post my table structure , i do the like keyword because  i need to get the country name from Like "Afganisthan fixed" when searching for Afganisthan also .